# How to catch images from a http webcam livestream

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, webcam, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I need to capture images from a webcam livestream that is provided [here](http://www.ag-wanderfalken.de/index.php?option=com_wrapper&Itemid=78)

Has anyone an idea how to do it?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090885/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-frames-as-images-out-of-fms-live-stream) answer but it doesn't help me. When I enter

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://85.126.233.214/heidelberg-live/stream1.flv -r 1 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg captured%d.jpg
```

It returns

```
[rtmp @ 0xc45f40] Cannot open connection tcp://85.126.233.214:1935
rtmp://85.126.233.214/heidelberg-live/stream1.flv: Connection timed out
Conversion failed!
```

This is what the livestream part of the website looks like:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  
src="http://www.blitzvideoserver06.de/blitzvideoplayer4.swf"  
width="480" 
height="420" 
style="undefined" 
id="blitzvideoplayer" 
name="blitzvideoplayer" 
bgcolor="#ffffff" 
quality="high" 
allowfullscreen="true"  
flashvars="videofile1=rtmp://85.126.233.214/heidelberg-live/stream1.flv&amp;

live=1&amp;
keinlogo=1&amp;
mitstartbutton=1&amp;
bgc=ffffff">
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use something as rtmpdump to specify all FLV meta data and mimc the behaviour of the original SWF file which is sure do custom there.

Please see the custom handshake and reset messages during the RTMP communications in the screenshot.

[image]

Best Regards,

Eugene

Comment: Ah ok, my IP was wrong. Your picture is showing the correct IP, thanks! I tried also to get the correct server address using wireshark following your example.
I can indeed see the correct IP but there is not the complete string which is needed for streaming the images which is `rtmp:///heidelberg-live/stream2.flv` (I got this from someone related to the website)
Wireshark only gives the information `62.113.221.5` and `heidelberg-live`.
Is there any way to get the full correct server address (shown above) using wireshark?

Comment: hey @mcExchange the original RTMP URL is correct. You need to see the handshake by yourself using WireShark and recreate the same communications using tools you have. Including information on the SWF, window, referrer, channel, etc.

Comment: So you mean I have to extract from `flashvars="videofile1=rtmp://85.126.233.214/heidelberg-live/stream1.flv&amp;` everything beginning from `rtmp` until `&amp` while replacing the IP with the one found by wireshark (`62.113.221.5`) ? Is this a rule? 
I would understand it if at least the `&amp` didn't have to be removed. Or is there always an `&amp` at the end of the address?